# Javascript - how to remove escape sequence looking like backlash?

Tags: javascript

```
 \\"http://www.google.com\"
```

I am trying to just get the href (http://www.google.com) but nothing I found online works. Below is a list of found solutions which I tried and which do not work.
Ps. the string with the escape sequence (as I understand its not just backlash) I am getting and cannot change. Thank you!!

```
str.replace(String.fromCharCode(92),String.fromCharCode(92,92)); //not working
str.replace(/\\/, "\\\\"); // not working
str.replace(/(\s)/g,function($0){return $0==' '?' ':'\\s'}) //not working
```

Comment: Try `str.replace(/[\\]/g, '')`

Comment: try this
`const str = "\\http://www.google.com";
console.log(str.replace("\\", ""));`

Comment: @choz thank you!! it works. I wonder why /\\/ didnt work and why I need []